# The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I am trying tog get my React Native app (with expo modules, but not built on expo) deployed to the Google Play Store, and I keep getting this error when I try to build...

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':expo' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10
```

My issue us, the line that it seems to be referencing, `project ':expo' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10` doesn't exist anywhere in my code, maybe in the node modules but I have no way of knowing.
I have absolutely no idea what kotlin is and never heard of it before this. I tried looking around for where to upgrade by kotlin-gradle-plugin, but thats nowhere in my app.json or package.json or any other config files. I saw some message boards with similar issues telling me to change this line inside of build.gradle

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0')
```

to make `7.3.0` match the version I need, but I firmly believe 7.3.0 is greater than 1.6.20, so I highly doubt that solution has any actual merits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the current version of expo-modules are incompatible with the latest version of React Native (0.70.0) and how it compiles Android Builds. I downgraded react-native to 0.69.5. This ultimately led **me** to other issues but hopefully this can help somebody else.